Не могу запустить kafka в docker
Пытался запустить кафку в docker-е командой
sudo docker run -it --network storager -p 9092:9092 --name kafka -v $SRC/dstorage/kafka:/bitnami/kafka bitnami/kafka

предварительно создал соответствующий network и папку dstorage/kafka для подключения тома.
Однако получал ошибку
mkdir: cannot create directory '/bitnami/kafka/config': Permission denied

и создавалась папка $SRC/dstorage/kafka от имени супрпользователя даже если уже была создана без прав суперпользователя
Погуглил, нашел инфу что нужно запускать контейнер без sudo
Сделал:
sudo groupadd docker

sudo usermod -aG docker $USER

reboot

Теперь позволяет запускать без sudo однако ошибка та же, но папка $SRC/dstorage/kafka больше не создается от sudo если ранее была создана без sudo.
Как запустить kafkа-у правильно без использования compose и прочих сторонних инструментов. Только командой в терминале подобной приведенной выше?
